# How to insert drop down list box in a Telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik Grid, with two columns I need to keep second column as drop-down list box with in the grid, I am using ASP.NET MVC control

Can any body tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the template of the column to embed arbitrary HTML. If using Ajax binding - try the client template. The following online examples will be helpful:

1. [Server templates](http://web.archive.org/web/20131116004646/http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesserverside)
2. [Client templates](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206160725/http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesclientside)

Comment: As you used links for this answer instead of answering directly here this answer is now useless as the links are 404ing.

Comment: I have updated the links to use The Way Back Machine's archive so the answer could still be useful. :)

Answer (score 6):

I need to do that for my project.
Here is how I did it:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Role).ClientTemplate(
                Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                    .Name("RoleList<#= UserID #>")
                    .BindTo(new SelectList(UserController.GetRoles()))
                    .ToHtmlString()
            );
```

The *static* method `GetRoles` returns a simple `IEnumerable` of `String`. You still can return a custom object by using a different `SelectList` constructor to specify `Value` and `Text` property of your custom object.

```
new SelectList(UserController.GetCustomRoles(), "RoleID", "ShortName")
```